# Save JSON Array from file into JSONArray (Object) In java

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have `JSON array` with some questions (for test) and I want to save this `JSON array` (from file) into Java `JSONArray` Object.

here is the `JSON`: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/teoriaapp.appspot.com/o/questions.json?alt=media&token=8393bbc0-f8f7-4736-bdc0-663c98c04420

I just want to store it inside an `Object` and then use it later (in Another `Activity`)

Comment: what you have tried so far ? please post the code

Comment: I don't have any code just want to get the JSONArray - onCreate(Activity)

Answer (score 0):

1: create class BaseRecords

```
public class BaseRecordsimplements Serializable
{
    private List<Record> records;

    // getters ans setters
}
```

2: create class BaseClass

```
public class Record implements Serializable
{
    private String title;
    private String answ1;
    private String answ2;
    private String answ3;
    private String corrAnsw;
    private String category;
    private String imageURL;

    // getter and setters
}
```

use gson for parsing

```
public static List<Record> convertJSONList(String jsonString)
    {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        //JsonArray rootObject = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();

        //JsonElement jsonElements = rootObject.getAsJsonArray();

        JsonElement jsonElements = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Record>>()
        {
        }.getType();
        List<Record> dayTasks = gson.fromJson(jsonElements, type);

        return dayTasks;
    }
```

Comment: JsonParse, JsonElement, Gson, TypeToken can't find any of those

Comment: @Yaniv  You need to import the library in your gradle file.  Do a google search.

Comment: @Kristy Welsh Name?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6' import this in your gradle